# Tuple item printing format

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a two list of tuple as follows.I want to print this tuples separated by ‘|’.How an I achieve this.

```
listoftuple =[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
listoftuple1 =[(3,4,5),(5,6,7),(9,0,9)]
```

I want the result to be printed as follows:

```
1|2 3|4 5|6
3|4|5 5|6|7,9|0|9
```

Comment: which version of python are you using and do you always know the size of the tuples

Comment: Why a comma in the second output?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> " ".join(map(lambda x: "|".join(map(str, x)), listoftuple1))
'3|4|5 5|6|7 9|0|9'
```

Comment: A generator expression is usually clearer than mapping a lambda. The inner map is fine, since it's using a builtin function. I'd use: `" ".join("|".join(map(str, x)) for x in listoftuple1)`

Answer (score 2):

Making it simple using `for loop, map and join`

**Code:**

```
listoftuple = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
listoftuple1 = [(3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (9, 0, 9)]

for lst1 in listoftuple:
    print "|".join(map(str, list(lst1))),

print ""

for lst2 in listoftuple1:
    print "|".join(map(str, list(lst2))),
```

**Output:**

```
1|2 3|4 5|6 
3|4|5 5|6|7 9|0|9
```

Now making it a little complicated and less readable

**Code2:**

```
print " ".join("|".join(map(str, list(lst2))) for lst2 in listoftuple1)
print " ".join("|".join(map(str, list(lst1))) for lst1 in listoftuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are excellent.
Alternatively:

```
' '.join(["|".join(str(k) for k in j) for j in listoftuple1])
```

Comment: `[i for i in listoftuple]` is just `listoftuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python3 answer (or python2 if you use `from __future__ import print_function`)

```
>>> class my_tup(tuple):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "|".join(repr(x) for x in self)
... 
>>> lot =[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> print(*map(my_tup, lot))
1|2 3|4 5|6
>>> lot =[(3,4,5),(5,6,7),(9,0,9)]
>>> print(*map(my_tup, lot))
3|4|5 5|6|7 9|0|9
```

If you have an objection to more than one line of code, as some here obviously do :)

```
print(*("|".join(repr(x) for x in y) for y in lot))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map each `tuple`s elements to `str` and then join them, then unpack a generator for that to a `print()` call with a custom separator:

```
>>> listoftuple = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> print(*('|'.join(map(str, t)) for t in listoftuple), sep=' ')
1|2 3|4 5|6
>>> print(*('|'.join(map(str, t)) for t in listoftuple1), sep=' ')
3|4|5 5|6|7 9|0|9
```

If you're using Python 2 rather than 3, you'll need `from __future__ import print_function`.